# Creating Evenly Distributed Dotted Outline for a Rounded Rectangle in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-layout

EDIT: The dash size of 10 in the code sample is arbitrary.  The dash size is whatever looks good.

Let's say in SwiftUI, you want to have a custom list item that has a dotted outline -- to serve as a "add item hint."

So you use a strokeBorder like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let items:[String] = ["a","b","c"]
    @State var itemsEmpty = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("toggle").onTapGesture {
            itemsEmpty.toggle()
        }
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            if !itemsEmpty {
                List{
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // The "list item hint" view
                List{
                    Text("ADD")
                        .listRowBackground(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15))
                                .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, dash: [10]))
                            
                        )
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Which results in this:

[image]

This same technique is used in [this Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/layingoutviews), but it is unsatisfactory to me because the lines (understandably) are not evenly distributed and we get a nasty truncation at the wrap-around point.

The only (also unsatisfactory) ways I can think of to solve this are:

A) To create the view using two mirrored shapes instead... (but this will still result in truncation... only it will be symmetrical trunctation this time).

B) Making some kind of "sun rays" radial gradient and stack two rounded rectangles in a way that gives the illusion that we have a dotted outline... (but the "heads and tails" of these lines will not be perpendicular to the outline path because the "sun rays" all originate at a single point)

C) Using the parametric equation for a squircle (squircle because a superellipse looks like crap IMO if it is rectangular) (which would need to be cut in half and stretched like limo) and creating a path from it, then drawing the dashes as intermittent lines along that path using t = 2 * (pi) / some divisor to establish the resolution.  The trouble with this is that the modified (limo-fied) shape would be a piecewise function and therefore cannot be driven by t.  Also even if it could be, the dashes would not be regular in size for somewhat obvious reasons I can't put into words.

How can this be done??

Comment: Try setting the dash to 5

Comment: Even if you could make it look OK by choosing the precise quantity... you don't know what size/perimeter the rectangle is going to ultimately have since it's a dynamic layout and could end up running on any device.

Comment: You will need to adjust the dash size depending on the perimeter, otherwise this would not work *mathematically*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash will not be truncated if the length of the stroke (perimeter of the shape) is a integer multiple of the dash size.

Therefore, you need to dynamically adjust the dash size according to the perimeter. See [this](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/paraarclength.aspx) and [this](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/arclength.aspx) for finding the arc length of parametric and non-parametric curves respectively. If this is too difficult to integrate, also consider calculating the lengths of each `CGPathElement`s in the underlying `CGPath` for the shape. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/janselv/4e8702d4ba9e88153f39be6b50710d65) (though it's written in Swift 2), or [this repo](https://github.com/louisdh/bezierpath-length) for how to do this.

In the case of the rounded rectangle with a corner radius, you can simply add up the lengths of the straight parts and the circular parts.

```
.listRowBackground(
    GeometryReader { geo in
        let strokeWidth: CGFloat = 4
        let radius: CGFloat = 15
        let insettedDiameter = radius * 2 - strokeWidth
        let desiredDash: CGFloat = 10
        // note that we need to take the inset of strokeBorder into account
        // or just use stroke instead of strokeBorder to make this simpler
        let perimeter = (geo.size.width - strokeWidth / 2 - insettedDiameter) * 2 + // horizontal straight edges
                        (geo.size.height - strokeWidth / 2 - insettedDiameter) * 2 + // vertical straight edges
                        (insettedDiameter * .pi) // the circular parts

        // this finds the smallest adjustedDash such that
        // - perimeter is an integer multiple of adjustedDash
        // - adjustedDash > desiredDash
        let floored = floor(perimeter / desiredDash)
        let adjustedDash = (perimeter - desiredDash * floored) / floored + desiredDash
        
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius)
            .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: strokeWidth, dash: [adjustedDash]))
    }
)
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: (psuedo code:) ... I think "(geo.size.width - strokeWidth / 2 - radius)" should be (assuming using stroke and *not* using strokeBorder) "((w - 2*radius) * 2)" correct?  Otherwise we are only substracting 1 radius when each side is missing two of them.  Also if we are using strokeBorder as in your answer, I think we should adjust the radius to be radius - strokeWidth/2 also.

Comment: @NerdyBunz Ah you are right. To avoid mistakes like this it's better to just calculate the length of `RoundedRectangle(...).inset(by: strokeWidth / 2).path(in: ...)` directly using the `CGPathElement`s.

Comment: Never tried that.  A bit too advanced for me but thanks for helping me find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested...

This is an alternate re-usable version where instead of defining a desired dash length, we set a desired number of dashes.

It also prevents a problematic odd number of dashes.

```
struct DottedRoundedRectangle: View {
    
    enum BorderPosition {
        case inset, centered
    }
    
    let evenNumberOfDashes: Int
    let color: Color
    let strokeWidth: Double
    let radius: Double
    let borderPosition: BorderPosition
    
    private var insetDistance: Double {
            switch borderPosition {
            case .centered:
                return 0
            case .inset:
                return strokeWidth / 2
            }
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let w = geo.size.width
            let h = geo.size.height
            
            // an odd number of dashes is bad -- results in back-to-back dashes at wrap around point
            let _evenNumDashes = evenNumberOfDashes + (evenNumberOfDashes % 2)
            
            let horizontalSideLength = (w - (2 * insetDistance)) - (2 * (radius - insetDistance))
            let verticalSideLength = (h - (2 * insetDistance)) - (2 * (radius - insetDistance))
            let cornerLength = Double.pi/2 * (radius - insetDistance)
           
            let perimeter = (horizontalSideLength * 2) + (verticalSideLength * 2) + (cornerLength * 4)
           
            let dashLength:Double = perimeter/Double(_evenNumDashes)
                    
            switch borderPosition {
            case .inset:
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius)
                    .fill(Material.ultraThin)
                    .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: strokeWidth, dash: [dashLength]))
                    .foregroundColor(color)
            case .centered:
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius)
                    .fill(Material.ultraThin)
                    .stroke(color, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: strokeWidth, dash: [dashLength]))
            }
           
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Nice. I'm trying to do something similar to this - I want to place N small views (Circle() for example) around the perimeter of a rounded rect like this. So basically instead of dashes, there would be evenly spaced small circles going around the border. Could this code be adapted to do that?